# Neo4j + NLP : Autocompletion of senteces

Tags: neo4j, nlp, cypher

I read the [article](http://jexp.de/blog/2015/01/natural-language-analytics-made-simple-and-visual-with-neo4j/) of Michael from Neo4j for NLP implementation with cypher queries in Neo4j. I think everyone should have a look, thanks for the useful Cypher queries. After I read, it bring new questions and ideas in which I made some search for algorithms, articles, code libraries (including Graphify) for couple of days but could not find a clear idea. So I would like to hear ideas from the Neo4j-people about the question:

In the article, sentences are splitted to individual words and associated with each other with `NEXT` relationship. The article covers some Cypher queries to play with the data based on your needs. So my question scenario is like this:

Think about we already have hundreds of thousands sentences (or words) stored in the Neo4j with `NEXT` relationship. So each word knows the predecessor/successor word coming before/after itself. Lets we have a app which uses this db and user types the part (lets say half) of the sentence and the app suggests for couple of possible words which would be grammatically convenient to progress with according to the data in the db. For ex:

```
Today I would like to play ........... (suggestions: guitar, football, etc...)
```

It sounds like the such machine learning algorithms should be in role since there will be supervised learning and iterations over the words in db. But can it be done with a cypher query as well? Sorry for this so abstract question without any code provided, just want to get some ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this would be possible you can give a strength to the relation.

example:

(I love)-[strength:100]->(beer)   or  (I love)-[strength:20]->( wine)

You can write a query that beer will be shown first. orderby limit. You can also set the relation if someone pick it +1 so the strength becomes 101. It is a recommendation. YOu can think about making it more complicated like

(i)-[strength:20]->(love)-[strenth:50]>(beer)

(i)-[strength: 101]->(beer)

So you have a relation between the first I and  beer and you calculate the total strength. ALso you can give labels ad search for a patterns.